# Are spellbook spells copied from scrolls also single-use?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock

My warlock has **Book of Ancient Secrets** which allows the warlock to copy spell scrolls into his Book of Shadows, provided he spends both the time and the rare inks.

When a copied spell is used, is the spellbook page the spell was copied to expended? The rules for spell scrolls state that, once used, the words disappear from the page and the paper dissolves. Since this feature is essentially duplicating a spell scroll, does it follow the same rules as spell scrolls?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The wizard's spellbook and the warlock's Book of Shadows don't have anything in their description that specify that they behave like spell scrolls.

Once a spell scroll is successfully copied into a spellbook or Book of Shadows, the only specifications regarding how spellcasting using them works are provided in the respective description for each class feature. They do not behave like spell scrolls; they don't disappear from the book after one use. (It'd be pointless to copy a scroll into a spellbook or Book of Shadows if they did disappear from the book after one use.)